# Change all occurrences after particular letter

Tags: regex, r, perl, replace

In a string, how do I change any 'e' that is to the right of an 'o' to 'a'?

I first tried this, but made only one change:

```
x <- c('keonele','keontele');
gsub('o.*\\Ke','a',x,perl=T);
[1] "keonela"  "keontela"
```

I then ran the input through the same command twice and got the right result:

```
x <- c('keonele','keontele');
x <- gsub('o.*\\Ke','a',x,perl=T);
x <- gsub('o.*\\Ke','a',x,perl=T);
[1] "keonala"  "keontala"
```

How do I make such changes exhaustively with one command?

Comment: I don't think you are using the correct meaning of "preceded". For your natural language description the answer should be "kaonele", "kaonela"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use negative lookahead

```
> x <- c('keonele','keontele')
> gsub("e(?!o)", "a", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "keonala"  "keontala"
```

It replaces all the `e`'s which was not immediately followed by the letter `o` with `a`.

**OR**

```
> gsub("^.*o(*SKIP)(*F)|e", "a", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "keonala"  "keontala"
```

`^.*?o` matches all the character from the start upto the last `o`.  `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to fail and now the pattern which was next to the OR operator will try to match characters from the remaining string. So the pattern `e` will match all the `e`'s which was after to last `o`. Replacing the `e` with `a` will give you the desired output.

Comment: If the target is 'kexonele' then your first fails and your second  succeeds. (And as is often the case, the question is too vague to allow a decision regarding which is correct, but I'm happy to upvote.

Comment: yep, that's why i added the second option. At first the question is unclear for me. Thanks for your comment..

Comment: I took your advice on `(SKIP)(*F)` and tweaked it a little bit and made it work. Thanks a bunch!